# OpenCV Issue Running GStreamer

Tags: opencv, debian, gstreamer, raspbian

I try to use the following project: https://github.com/skaringa/emeocv

I use an raspberryPi 3B+ with raspbian 11.4 (debian 11.4)

The script can be called with the following command: `sudo ./emeocv -c libcamerasrc -a -vINFO`

When I call the above mentioned command I got this error:

```
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1824) handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Embedded video playback halted; module v4l2src0 reported: Internal data stream error.
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (914) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to start pipeline
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (501) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
INFO    : adjustCamera
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  OpenCV(4.5.1) ../modules/highgui/src/window_gtk.cpp:624: error: (-2:Unspecified error) Can't initialize GTK backend in function 'cvInitSystem'

Aborted
```

Any Hints for me? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your project looks great, but it's hard to find exactly the reason..
The error is from GStreamer, where is it specified?

v4l2src0 gives the error - can you run the command?

gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,framerate=90/1 ! autovideoconvert ! autovideosink

Comment: somewhere in the main.cpp

Comment: no I got this: -bash: gst-launch-1.0: command not found

Comment: If you want to use RPi camera, can you run the first 3 steps from here?
https://pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/30/accessing-the-raspberry-pi-camera-with-opencv-and-python/

Comment: I have a normal usb webcam at the moment. 
I think the issue is the opencv version. How can I install a specific version of a package. I need opencv 4.2.0 

thats the install package  `apt-get install libopencv-dev` but if I add 4.2.0 at the end the package is not found

Comment: try to use:

apt list -a libopencv-dev

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247971/discussion-between-maxim-lyuzin-and-felix).

Comment: returns: 

`pi@waterpi:~ $ sudo apt list -a libopencv-dev
Listing... Done
libopencv-dev/stable 4.5.1+dfsg-5 armhf`

Comment: solved this issue. I run it without sudo and use a more modern camera now it works. ... Thanks for your help